How to pick part of a list of scripts
From another code, I obtained the following list:
{"http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347\">On", "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512\">On"}

I only need to extract the list of http://..., excluding \">On" and all " around url links. The output should be:
{http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347, http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512}

Pattern recognition code will be most suitable as I have a large list at hand.
Thanks.

To remove the suffix from the strings, you could use StringDelete:
input = {"http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347\">On", "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512\">On"};
StringDelete[input, "\">On"]
(* {"http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347", "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512"} *)

To make sure you only remove suffixes (and prefixes), you could use StringTrim:
StringTrim[input, "\">On"]

But you said

...excluding ">On" and all " around url links.

which seems to imply that you don't want strings in your result. But a raw sequence of characters like http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347 will not parse as a valid WL expression. You can, however, wrap the strings with URL:
URL /@ StringDelete[input, "\">On"]
(* {URL["http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347"], URL["http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512"]} *)

That doesn't satisfy your desire to have no quotes at all, but I'm not sure what else you could possibly want.

You are perfectly right! I wanted to have what you have just described above. My intention with removing all " was to keep URL links as clickable but my request was not in line with my intention. You have corrected me! Thanks.

list = {
        "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347\">On", 
        "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512\">On"
       };

Using Stringsplit:
Flatten[StringSplit[list, x__ ~~ "\">On" :> x]]


{"http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347", "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512"}

Or using StringReplace:
StringReplace[list, x__ ~~ "\">On" :> x]


{"http://lex.uz/en/docs/6959347", "http://lex.uz/en/docs/6956512"}

